# How Can I relate 2 content items in GraphQl in orchard?

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms, orchard-modules, orchardcore

I want to write a GraphQl query in the Orchard with these conditions:

I have a content type for Office and another one for City
Now I want to receive all the offices in Newyork city.
But the problem is that in the where condition of the GraphQl I don't see any condition for filtering a specific city.

What can  I do?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a taxonomy for cities and then add a taxonomy field with Cities taxonomy to your Office content type.

Enable Queries Feature, which is a module that enables you to write Lucene or SQL queries and expose them to GraphQL.

Add a SQL query.

1. Add name getOfficesByCity
2. Add schema

```
{
"type": "ContentItem/Office"
}
```

3. Check the Return Documents checkbox.
4. Write SQL that will query TaxonomyIndex for Offices with specific `TermContentItemId`.
   Something along the lines

```
SELECT
    ti.DocumentId
FROM
    TaxonomyIndex ti
WHERE
    ti.TermContentItemId = @cityItemId
    AND ti.ContentType = 'Office'
```

5. Go to GraphQL

```
query MyQuery {
  getOfficesByCity(parameters: "{\"cityItemId\":\"4rx2d0cqr8h7fyzdq95hb45scj\"}") {
    displayText
  }
}
```